# Zeppelin default limits

Tags: apache-zeppelin

Just to comment that this excellent tool, from my prospective, it should able to handle more data. I've been struggling for a while trying to pass the default limits of 10K rows (JDBC) and ZEPPELIN_INTERPRETER_OUTPUT_LIMIT > 100KB. You should be able to handle 10x or more easily. I have the JVM set to 5GB.

Please, a list of things to tweak to handle more data it would be really nice.

Anyway congrats for the tool. Excellent work

Answer (score 0):

Change the appropriate environment variables in **conf/zeppelin-env.sh**, and restart the server.

More info:
https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/setup/operation/configuration.html